# jQuery Blur Fires Before href

Tags: jquery, blur

I am trying to use an Ajax search\suggest box. I use jQuery to handle the textbox losing focus. However, when I click on a link in the suggestion list jQuery fires the blur event and the link is not followed. Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#lstxt').click(function() {
        this.value = '';
    });
    $('#lstxt').blur(function() {
        this.value = 'Database Search';
        document.getElementById('ls').innerHTML='';
        document.getElementById('ls').style.border='0px';
    });
});
```

How do I get it to not fire .blur if a link is being clicked inside the suggestion list (id="ls_table")?

Answer (score 6):

```
var global_switch = false;
$('#ls_table').hover (
  function () { global_switch = true; },
  function () { global_switch = false; }
)
$('#lstxt').blur(function() {
  if (global_switch) { return; } else { ...});
```

This is *just a proof of concept*. As always, global variables are bad. Take a look at jQuery's [data API](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data) to circumvent it.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

The method I used when implementing my own is adding a slight delay:

```
$('#lstxt').blur(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // original blur code here
    }, 250);
});
```

Definitely not the best solution (but usually works). But Boldewyn's solution should work -- assuming that #ls_table has been created before trying to assign it. If you're creating/destroying #ls_table frequently, you can bind the event to the parent element:

```
// just using the data API for jquery.
$('#ls').hover(
    function(){ $('#ls').data('autocompleteover', 1); },
    function(){ $('#ls').data('autocompleteover', 0); }
);
$('#lstxt').blur(function(){
    if($('#ls').data('autocompleteover'))
        return;
    // original blur code here
}
```

Comment: That's not the right way. But till now that is the best way that In know how to work href even blur functionality is there

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#lstxt').click(function() {
        this.value = '';
        return true;
    });
    $('#lstxt').blur(function() {
        this.value = 'Database Search';
        $('#ls').html('').css('border',"0px");
        return true;
    });
});
```

edit: 
blur will fire if you click outside of a textbox. is lstxt a textbox?

**edit2:** you will need to unbind the blur event and rebind it conditionally. i would need more info about your page layout to tell you how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I manage similar problem (with some custom validator on blur, which was fired before click on close button - but I want to close dialog (click) without this blur event fired)
code on input (with validator):

```
      ..
      $(this).blur({validators: validators}, function(event){ // blur                                                
      (function($this){
         validator_timeout = setTimeout(function(){ // validator_timeout is global
           $this.validate(event.data.validators); // do some validation
         }, 50); // delay just minimum of time, but enough to let other event to be fired
       }($(this))); // passing $(this) to function
      });...
```

and on other event handler, like close dialog, when we don't want to call function on validate, just clear validator_timeout to suppress blur:

```
   click_function = function(){                        
       clearTimeout(validator_timeout);
       $( this ).dialog( "close" );
   }
```

Hope it will be useful for someone.